# Forcing HTTPS version without redirect in case of direct visit

Tags: html, .htaccess, https

I know that I am able to write a redirection rule which redirects to HTTPS version if someone sends a request on HTTP version of an URL. But how to implement that if an user wants to visit my site directly using only domain name: `example.com`, he gets the `https://` version without redirect? I also know about HSTS, but I am pretty sure that this can be accomplished only with good `.htaccess` settings?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

If you type a URL into a browser without explicitly stating the scheme, then **the browser** will default to plain HTTP.

The only way to change that would to rewrite the browser the user has installed (or perhaps to have them install a browser plugin).

---

`.htaccess` is a [recommended *against*](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html) mechanism for configuring Apache HTTPD. The HTTP server you use cannot influence the URL the browser requests (other than by recieving a request and responding with a redirect).

Comment: One way may be to get on the browser's hardcoded HSTS list, but that's something of an impractical long shot…

Comment: that is weird, because for example when I type marketingminer.com into browser, I get HTTPS without redirect and HSTS is not set up

Comment: @TomášNosek — I cannot reproduce that — https://i.imgur.com/fCQmFMS.png — perhaps your browser has cached the 301 one response.

Comment: I have also tested it using anonymous browser @Quentin I still get HTTPS